# GetFile AWS S3 .NET 6 C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-6.0, aws-s3-client

I have these two types of method to get the file in S3.

```
//method 1
var client = new AmazonS3Client();

            var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = fileName,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(300),
            };

            var presignedUrlResponse = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
            return presignedUrlResponse;
```

```
//method 2
var client = new AmazonS3Client();
            var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = fileName,
            };
            var file = await client.GetObjectAsync(BucketName, fileName);
            return File(file.ResponseStream, file.Headers.ContentType);
```

In my method 1 by using GetPreSignedURL it saves the name of the region in the path of the photo and I don't want that, I need it to save without, because then I can't open the photo in the browser.
Example: `https://service-manager-estagio.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/urlphoto`
I want to save without this *sa-east-1*

In my method 2 on the *return File* line I can't use this File, the message is that I can't use it as a method

I need help using method 1 and saving without the region name or using method 2 with this File.
But if anyone knows another way to do this GET is valid too.
Thanks!!

Comment: Sorted out! Method 1, I was re-creating the S3 Client, I just deleted it and used what I had created up there and as dependency injection.  ``` var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = fileName,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            };
            return _awsS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request); ```